# Filter JSON via SplitJson and MergeContent

Tags: apache-nifi

I'm building flow in nifi and in the flow I need to filter JSON by a filed. So I decided to split json then merge filtered parts via SplitJson and MergeContent processors. My splitJson proccesor JsonPath is `$.items[?(@.name =~ /.*Test.*/i)]`  so it splits correct but when I want to merge all parts into one json file `(Merge Strategy = Defragment)` and it merge files but incorrect way. For example:

**Input**

```
{ "items": [  { "name": "A" }, { "name": "B" }, { "name": "Test" }, { "name": "Test" } ] }
```

**So I expect from MergeContent Processor this:**

```
[ {"name":"Test"}, {"name":"Test"} ]
```

**but I got**

```
{"name":"Test"}{"name":"Test"}
```

so this is even not a json

The ideal variant is to merge somehow:

```
{ "items":[
{"name": "Test"},
{"name": "Test"}
]}
```

How to merge like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Configure [**`MergeContent Processor`**](https://community.hortonworks.com/questions/178086/json-split-and-then-converted-to-csv-before-being.html) as described below

- Delimiter Strategy as **`Text`**
- Header as **`[`**
- Footer as **`]`**
- Demarcator as **`,`**

Now your **output flowfile** from **`MergeContent`** processor will result as

```
[ {"name":"Test"}, {"name":"Test"} ]
```